# Bug: tag auto-complete always replaces the first tag even other words are prompted

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow

Repro:
1. Ask Question
2. Input "bug" and space
3. Input "stack" and select "stackoverflow"

Expected: "bug stackoverflow"
Current:  "stackoverflow stack"

Under IE 7

Comment: no-reproduce on FF 3.5.5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the browser. IE and Opera don't provide adequate JavaScript control over the caret in a textbox, from my understanding. Can't be "fixed" for that reason.

(works OK in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.)

Also related to whether you select with keyboard or mouse. AFAIK workaround is to use the keyboard for input on tags field.

Comment: Verified on Firefox.